# How to match text in string in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I have some issues with Arduino about how to match text.

I have:

```
String tmp = +CLIP: "+37011111111",145,"",,"",0
```

And I am trying to match:

```
if (tmp.startsWith("+CLIP:")) {
    mySerial.println("ATH0");
}
```

But this is not working, and I have no idea why.

I tried `substring`, but the result is the same. I don't know how to use it or nothing happens.

Where is the error?

Comment: how does the first line even compile (I tried it in Arduiono/Wiring)? What is CLIP? Can you post working/compilable code (for instance the declaration of mySerial)?

Comment: Peter in this example it will not work. I just put this for example that I get from Arduino Serial monitor. I solved my problem with **substring**, just let for anyone to know, that Arduino in Serial monitor don't show \r and \n and thats was my biggest problem.

Comment: @Min2liz If my answer helped. Could you please accept it as the correct one?

Answer (score 7):

```
bool Contains(String s, String search) {
    int max = s.length() - search.length();

    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
        if (s.substring(i) == search) return true; // or i
    }

    return false; //or -1
}
```

Otherwise you could simply do:

```
if (readString.indexOf("+CLIP:") >=0)
```

I'd also recommend visiting:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/String

Answer (score 2):

I modified the code from gotnull. Thanks to him to put me on the track.

I just limited the search string, otherwise the substring function was not returning always the correct answer (when substrign was not ending the string). Because substring search always to the end of the string.

```
int StringContains(String s, String search) {
    int max = s.length() - search.length();
    int lgsearch = search.length();

    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
        if (s.substring(i, i + lgsearch) == search) return i;
    }

 return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//+CLIP: "43660417XXXX",145,"",0,"",0
if (strstr(command.c_str(), "+CLIP:")) { //Someone is calling
    GSM.print(F("ATA\n\r"));
    Number = command.substring(command.indexOf('"') + 1);
    Number = Number.substring(0, Number.indexOf('"'));
    //Serial.println(Number);
} //End of if +CLIP:
```

This is how I'm doing it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (tmp.startsWith(String("+CLIP:"))) {
    mySerial.println("ATH0");
}
```

You can't put the string with quotes only you need to cast the variable :)